# What is Nominal bit rate?

Tags: can-bus

I am new to CAN protocol. I am trying to understand the bit timing concept. Wiki states "All nodes on the CAN network must operate at the same nominal bit rate".

Are bit rate and nominal bit rate same or different?

Comment: thanku @vikash Singh

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the [Bosch CAN specification](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf)?

> NOMINAL BIT RATE
>   The Nominal Bit Rate is the number of bits per
>   second transmitted in the absence of resynchronization by an ideal
>   transmitter.

Next question: "What is resynchronization?"
See same document.